# I'm not able to send attachments to CA Rally/Agile Central from automation code

Tags: java, groovy, automation, rally

I am getting the below error while trying to attach content to rally using the rally api.

Error occurred creating Attachment: 
Not authorized to create: AttachmentContent.

I'm able to manually attach documents. I'm also able to create testcase from my automation code... but not able to send attachments.

Below is the code. i even tried to add workspace and project ref.

```
                                       JsonObject myAttachmentContent = new JsonObject();
                                       myAttachmentContent.addProperty("ProjecT", projectRef);
                           myAttachmentContent.addProperty("Workspace", workspaceRef);
                   myAttachmentContent.addProperty("Content", imageBase64String);
                       CreateRequest attachmentContentCreateRequest = new CreateRequest("AttachmentContent",myAttachmentContent);
                   CreateResponse attachmentContentResponse = restApi.create(attachmentContentCreateRequest);
                   if (attachmentContentResponse.wasSuccessful())
                   {   
                   String myAttachmentContentRef = attachmentContentResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString();
                   System.out.println("Attachment Content created: " + myAttachmentContentRef);
                   JsonObject myAttachment = new JsonObject();
                   myAttachment.addProperty("TestCaseResult", testCaseResultRef);
                   myAttachment.addProperty("Content", myAttachmentContentRef);
                   myAttachment.addProperty("Name", "AttachmentFromREST.jpg");
                   myAttachment.addProperty("Description", "Attachment From REST");
                   myAttachment.addProperty("ContentType","image/jpg");
                   myAttachment.addProperty("Size", attachmentSize);
                   myAttachment.addProperty("User", userRef);
                   myAttachment.addProperty("Project", projectRef);
                   myAttachment.addProperty("Workspace", workspaceRef);

                   CreateRequest attachmentCreateRequest = new CreateRequest("Attachment", myAttachment);
                                   CreateResponse attachmentResponse = restApi.create(attachmentCreateRequest);
                   String myAttachmentRef = attachmentResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString();
                   System.out.println("Attachment  created: " + myAttachmentRef);



                   if (attachmentResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
                       System.out.println("Successfully created Attachment");
                   } else {
                       String[] attachmentContentErrors;
                       attachmentContentErrors = attachmentResponse.getErrors();
                       System.out.println("Error occurred creating Attachment: ");
                       for (int i=0; i<attachmentContentErrors.length;i++) 
                                                {
                           System.out.println(attachmentContentErrors[i]);
                        }
                          }
                   }
                     else {
                       String[] attachmentContentErrors;
                       attachmentContentErrors = attachmentContentResponse.getErrors();
                       System.out.println("Error occurred creating Attachment: ");
                       for (int i=0; i<attachmentContentErrors.length;i++) {
                           System.out.println(attachmentContentErrors[i]);
                       }
                   }
```

Comment: Why is this tagged Groovy?  This is Java no?

Answer (score 0):

Is it just a small typo with this line?

```
myAttachmentContent.addProperty("Project", projectRef); //"Project", not "ProjecT
```

Otherwise your code looks ok to me...

Comment: I found this other example, which is adding an attachment to a test case result: https://github.com/RallyCommunity/rally-java-rest-apps/blob/master/CreateTestResultAddAttachment.java#L85
Seems pretty similar to your code.  Usually not authorized to create errors just mean the user doesn't have access to that project...